# why when i launch my app with emrun i received .py missing?

Tags: python

i want try to deploy one little browser application. (it's only a button that do nothing). When I try to debug and run my app with emrun, I receive:

```
C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I had understand that ".py" is missing but I don't know how to fix it.
I'm using window 10.

Comment: What's your command?

Comment: can you explain your question? because the code actually will do nothing, only show the mainwindow

Answer (score 0):

The path to the file is wrong

It tries to open the file in the dir 'C:'  what is not correct.
Change the file to the dir where the file is saved.

Comment: ok, but i have not the file ".py" and i don't know how to change the dir  for the launcher

Comment: yes sure, but there is nothing in the code.

mainwindow_H

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

mainwindow_ccp

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
}